# SIFT returns different size descriptors

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, sift, feature-descriptor

I'm trying to extract SIFT descriptors in order to cluster them later.
I have this piece of code

```
images = d.values()[0]
labels = d.values()[1]

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

des = [[] for i in range(10)]
for im in zip(images, labels):
    #des[im[1]].append(sift.detectAndCompute(img_2_RGB_cv2_format(im[0]), None))
    k,d = sift.detectAndCompute(img_2_RGB_cv2_format(im[0]), None)
    print len(d)
```

and I see that `len(d)` gives varying values from 4 to 20 (from what I see in a glance, could be even further).

Is it possible use different number of descriptors? Should I try to get a constant number of descriptors?

Comment: You can never expect to have the same number of features. For e.g. imagine one of your pictures was just completely black. Would you expect that it has 1000 features like another image? Of course not. The number of features doesn't matter in clustering if you use an algorithm like `knn` (in OpenCV as `knnMatch()`). You just try to find the nearest neighbor for each descriptor, this can be done regardless of the number between them.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I tried using SVM and I was under the impression that SVM requires same number of features.
Can you show the how to use KNN for a pair `[descriptors, labels]` where descriptors is list of descriptors per image, and labels is the label for each image? I only saw KNN for 2 images...

Comment: What are you trying to do here, separate scenes in a set of images? Or do a reverse image search? You can just do knn and similar on each pair of images usually. I've not implemented a SVM with feature descriptors before so can't help you out there.

Comment: I want to classify images based on training (SVM, preferably) images' features

Comment: Oh, I see. Yeah for an SVM you'll want to use a model like a visual bag of words, which will not vary in size. Basically this is a histogram of feature descriptors, so you can count occurrences in a set bin size. You can read the general idea on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision).

Comment: But I really don't understand how to keep them the same size (i.e. same num of keypoints). I can create a max limit of keypoints, but that doesn't help, as most have different numbers < limit

Comment: You're definitely missing the point of the BoW model! Say you want to classify similar text documents. They of course don't share the same number of words. But you build a codebook and then you take a histogram of the codebook. Think of a histogram of color values---whether one image is all black, or the other is random colored noise, they'll have the same size histogram descriptor---it's just counts of a set number of bins. The idea is the same here, but feature descriptors are your words. See [here](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~mostajabi/Tutorial.html) for e.g. (and read through the wiki link!)